# adding a value to a set in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
def CreateDataBaseByActor(file):
   dataBase = dict()
   set = {}
   f = open(file,"r")
   for line in f:
       set = line.split(', ')
       for movie in set[1:]:
           dataBase[movie] = set[0]
   return dataBase
```

> i have a file that each line is written by the format: actor_name, movie1, movie2, movie3...
>   example:

- Sylvester Stallone, Rocky, Rambo, Assassins
- Julianne Moore, Assassins, Hannibal

  > the problem is that when i try to add to a movie, another actor name (for example: in the first line, the key - Assassins- has the value Sylvester Stallone, and in the second line value of - Assassin - is replaced instead of added)

Comment: What do you think `set = line.split(', ')` is doing to the earlier defined `set = {}`? Plus sets don't have indices and don't support slicing, in case you're planning to use them that way.

Comment: `set = {}`  doesn't create a set. It creates a dictionary named set. It's not a good idea to use that name anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to return a dictionary that maps movie titles to a list of actors within each (which isn't clear from the name of the function), then this code should do it for you.  (Note that I changed the variable named `set` to be called `fields` since it's not a good idea to name variables after types.)

```
def CreateDataBaseByActor(file):
   dataBase = dict()
   f = open(file, "r")
   for line in f:
       fields = line.split(', ')
       actor = fields[0]
       for movie in fields[1:]:
           dataBase.setdefault(movie, []).append(actor)
   return dataBase
```